# Listview subitem position (C# Forms)

Tags: c#, forms, listview, position

I want to get the position of a ListView item / subitem. What I mean by that is that I want to get a Left and a Top for this subitem. This is the position I mean:

[image]
.

I tried this:

```
int item_x = list.Items[1].SubItems[2].Bounds.X;
int item_y = list.Items[1].SubItems[2].Bounds.Y;
```

But it doesn't seem to give the correct position I want.

Comment: I think you need to take your coordinates of the ListView in concern. I think (I don't know or tested if your code is working) that your code will return the coordinates relative to your listview. If your listview is in a container in stead of directly on the form you should take this also into account

Comment: Actually the numbers look fine to me. Correct coordinates within the Listview, Header height included.. What are they and what would you expect?

Comment: It just can't be correct... This is where the position becomes http://spunit.cf/x/scrn352.png

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that what I wrote before was kind of correct. It just needed correcting with some adding and subtracting, then it showed like this: http://spunit.cf/x/scrn370.png.

Thanks for making me realize this =).

Here's the code for it:

```
int item_l = list.Items[1].SubItems[2].Bounds.Left + 3;
int item_t = list.Items[1].SubItems[2].Bounds.Top + 29;
int item_w = list.Items[1].SubItems[2].Bounds.Width - 1;
int item_h = list.Items[1].SubItems[2].Bounds.Height - 1;

ListView listt = new ListView();
Controls.Add(listt);
listt.BringToFront();
listt.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(item_l, item_t), new Size(item_w, item_h));
```